# Command 'UI5: Export to i18n' resulted in an error (command 'ui5plugin.exportToi18n' not found)

Tags: visual-studio-code, internationalization, sapui5

After installing a vscode extension named "[SAPUI5 extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iljapostnovs.ui5plugin&ssr=false#overview)", I get the following error everytime I try to execute the command "ui5 ...":
[image: error]

Did someone face this issue before?
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: As this is an extension specific error, contact the author directly by creating an issue on https://github.com/iljapostnovs/VSCodeUI5Plugin/issues

Comment: Thank you, I just did so